# sqlserverspatial110.dll vs sqlspatial130.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dll, sql-server-2016

I am trying to move a deployment to a new Azure VM with SQL Server 2016.  I am receiving the following error when trying to run the mvc app locally on the server.

> Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The fix for me was to manually copy sqlserver110.dll to the c:\windows\system32 folder on the new server.  I feel this is a step backwards, and I should really be trying to redirect the call to the sqlserver130.dll that installed on the new server by default with SS 2016.  I tried updating EF 5 to the latest version, but this did not seem to fix the issue.  Any suggestions?